# Absolutely irreducible/simple $A$-module iff Endomorphism ring consists of scalar matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra, division-algebras

Let $A$ be a non-commutative $K$-algebra (where $K$ a field),
whose underlying $K$-vector space is finite dimensional.

**Definition** An $A$-module $M$ is said to be
*absolutely irreducible* or *abs. simple* if for every extension field $E$ of $K$,
the $M \otimes_K E$ is a irreducible $A \otimes_K E$-module.

Remark. The terminology *simple* and *irreducible module* means the same.

**Theorem 2.3**. (from these notes:
[https://www.imsc.res.in/~amri/topics/modular.pdf](https://www.imsc.res.in/%7Eamri/topics/modular.pdf) )
An irreducible $A$-module $M$ is *absolutely irreducible* if
and only if every $A$-module endomorphism of $M$ is multiplication by a
scalar in the ground field, ie $\operatorname{End}_A(M) =K$.

I not completely understand the proof of the direction
$\operatorname{End}_A(M) =K$ implies
$M$ absolutely irreducible:

> *Proof.* We know from Schur’s lemma that
> $D := \operatorname{End}_A(M)$ is a division
> ring. This division ring is clearly a finite dimensional vector space over
> $K$ (in fact a subspace of $\operatorname{End}_K(M)=K^{d^2}$).
> The image $B:=s(A)$ of $A$ in $\operatorname{End}_K(M)$ under canonical
> map $s:A \to \operatorname{End}_K(M)$ induced by $A$-module structure is
> a matrix algebra $M_n(D)$ over $D$. **Why?**
> $M$ can be realised as a minimal left
> ideal in $M_n(D)$. M is an absolutely irreducible $A$-module if and only
> if it is an absolutely irreducible $B$-module.

> If $\operatorname{End}_A(M) = K$, then $B = M_n(K)$, and $M \cong  K^n$.
> $B
>  \otimes_K E = M_n(E)$, and $M \otimes_K E = E^n$.
> Thus $ M \otimes_K E$ is clearly an irreducible
> $B \otimes_K E $ module. Therefore, $M$ is absolutely irreducible.

Several steps appear nebulous to me.

1. Why is the image $B:=s(A)$ of $A$ in $\operatorname{End}_K(M)$ is
   a matrix algebra $M_n(D)$ over $D$? [Wedderburn–Artin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%E2%80%93Artin_theorem) implies that $B$ is a direct product of matrix algebras $\operatorname{Mat}_{n_i}(D_i)$, $D_i$ divisor rings. Why $B$ consists of only one such factor?
2. How $M$ should be realised as a minimal left ideal in $M_n(D)$. Is there used tacitly certain structure result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, to go from a product of $M_n(D_i)$ to a single one, observe that the representation of $B$ is both faithful and simple. If we had a product of matrices over division rings, then we would have nontrivial central idempotents which act non trivially by faithfulness, contradicting simplicity.

For your second question, I think we are tacitly using the structure theorem of modules over $M_n(D)$, that they are all direct sums of the standard module $D^n$. It doesn’t seem relevant that we can realise $M$ as a minimal left ideal, aside from potentially making things more concrete (thinking of $M$ as matrices supported on a single column).

Overall one can think of this proof as being entirely a fact about the representation theory of matrices over division algebras, and the first part is the reduction step to this case.

It’s also probably worth keeping in mind that as categories, modules over $D$ and modules over $M_n(D)$ are equivalent, given by tensoring with the standard binodule. So after this first reduction step, one can pretend $n=1$ to make things a bit more concrete.

Comment: Why is the rep $B \subset End_K(M)$ simple?

Comment: also, you noted that the is a structure theorem of (fin gen?) $M_n(D)$ that they all are direct sums of D^n$ . Could you give a reference where I could look up this result?

Comment: The rep of $B$ is simple since we assumed $M$ is simple, any nonzero $B$ sub module of $M$ is also a nonzero $A$ sub module of $M$. I’m not sure of a reference for that statement, but it’s not hard to prove it yourself, first prove it for $n=1$ by checking that your favourite linear algebra proof for fields also works for division rings, then use the equivalence of categories of modules between $M_n(D)$ and $D$ given by tensoring with the bimodule of row/columns with entries in $D$. I suspect there’s also a slicker proof using semisimplicity in terms of the all modules reducible definition too

Comment: Thank you, I understand the argument now. By the way I found also a result answering my 2nd question on identification with minimal left ideals: That's Corollary 4.5 (p 651) in Lang's Algebra